# Spring Aspects (AspectJ) does not seem to work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

Well I really don't know why this does not work:

Every jar needed is in the place. Including `aspectjrt`.
Basically I start with configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "some.path" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SomeConf { ... }
```

Then I have my `Aspect`:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ControllerLoggerAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* some.path.ATest.*(..))")
    private void aspectTest() {
        System.out.println("\n\n ASPECT WORKING \n\n");
    }
}
```

Under `some.path` I have `Atest` class:

package some.path;

```
public class ATest {

    public void dummyMethod(){
        System.out.println("\n\n\nDummy static executed\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

Imagine now that I have controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping")
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/something")
    public ResponseEntity<String> publish(@RequestParam("Id") Long[] ids) {
        //aspect should be invoked here
        new ATest().dummyMethod();

        return new ResponseEntity<>("{ \"status\": \"stubbed\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Everything is invoked properly except aspect method. No errors, no exceptions, nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring AOP only works on Spring beans, i.e. if you want to intercept one of its methods, class `ATest` needs to be a `@Component`.

Comment: Partly true, and true in this case (auto-proxying). Spring also supports CTW and LTW, neither of which needs Spring beans (see `@Configurable`).

Comment: I know that, because I am a hardcore AspectJ user, not a Spring AOP user. But I guess the question was about Spring AOP.

Comment: Spring AOP has two modes.

Comment: No, Spring AOP is always proxy-based. There are no "two modes". If you use AspectJ within Spring it is not called Spring AOP anymore, it is just AspectJ within Spring.

Comment: Since 3.1, the Spring aspect support has provided declarative strategies in `AdviceMode` that will apply advice either using JDK proxies or AspectJ weaving. Using `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ`, for example, makes `@Transactional` work on self-calls.

Comment: As I said: I know. It works on self-calls because it is simply AspectJ!!! Because this is simply how AspectJ works, with or without Spring. It is totally unrelated to Spring, AspectJ works for any JVM language inside or outside of any container or application server. If you use AspectJ mode it is not Spring AOP anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the **advice** you want execute. The **pointcut** only helps in determining the join points. The advice will be executed, not the pointcut.

You could write a Advice like this using your pointcut "aspectTest()":

```
@Before("aspectTest()")
public void beforeAdvice(){
     System.out.println("\n\n ASPECT WORKING \n\n");
}
```

Or you could just replace your Pointcut annotation in the example with an advice annotation like this:

```
@Before("execution(* some.path.ATest.*(..))")
public void aspectTest() {
    System.out.println("\n\n ASPECT WORKING \n\n");
}
```

Here you have a list of all adivces:

- @Before("aspectTest()")
- @After("aspectTest()")
- @AfterReturning(pointcut = "aspectTest()", returning="retVal")
- @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "aspectTest()", throwing="ex")
- @Around("aspectTest()")

Comment: Tried second solution with Before, does not work. Hovever @Before("execution(public * *(..))") show some aspect output but also corrupts execution of a program.

Comment: Maybe you have to declare your method aspectTest as public. Otherwise spring can't execute it....

Comment: Well doesn't change a thing